# Parser Bing browser

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parsing

I created web parser for google and it is works good. Here I get top 5 results and show a user in my program. Attached code:

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SearchDemos.Controllers
{
    public class SearchInfo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }

        public string BTitle { get; set; }
        public string BLink { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SearchController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("Google")]
        public IList<SearchInfo> DoGoogleSearch(string q)
        {
            var html = @"https://www.google.com/search?q="+q ;

            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            //  accept-language : RU or EN 
            var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);


            var rows = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='r']").Take(5);

            var result = new List<SearchInfo>();
            foreach (HtmlNode row in rows)
            {
                var nodeRef = row.SelectSingleNode("./a");

                var si = new SearchInfo
                {

                    Link = nodeRef.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty),
                    Title = nodeRef.InnerText.Trim()
                };

                result.Add(si);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

My HTML page

```
@page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Search page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="~/css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <!-- Another variation with a button -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Google & Bing" id="txtQuery">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="btnSearch">
                    <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="searchResults">

        </div>

    </section>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                $("#btnSearch").click(function () {

                    $("#searchResults").html("");

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: '@Url.Action("Google", "Search")',
                        data: {
                            q: $("#txtQuery").val()
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            for (var i in data) {
                                var item = data[i];
                                console.log(item.title);
                                var p = $("<p></p>").text(item.title);
                                $("#searchResults").append(p);

                               /* console.log(item.append);
                                var h = $(" < p ></p >").text(item.a);
                                $("#searchResults").url(h);*/

                            }
                            console.log("data received");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Server error!");
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This part works good.
After that I tried create parser for bing browser and it doesn't work. But I used like in my example. What's happened?

Here I get a error in a line("System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')'
"). But I get data from UI. My q!=null

```
var rows = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='b_algo']").Take(5);
```

My controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace SearchDemos.Controllers
{
    public class SearchInfo
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }

        public string BTitle { get; set; }
        public string BLink { get; set; }
    }

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class SearchController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("Bing")]
        public IList<SearchInfo> DoBingSearch(string q)
        {
            var html = @"https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + q;

            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

            var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);


            var rows = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='b_algo']").Take(5);

            var result = new List<SearchInfo>();
            foreach (HtmlNode row in rows)
            {
                var nodeRef = row.SelectSingleNode("./a");                //here could be  var nodeRef = row.SelectSingleNode("//a");      

                var si = new SearchInfo
                {

                    BLink = nodeRef.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty),
                    BTitle = nodeRef.InnerText.Trim()
                };

                result.Add(si);
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

And HTML

```
@page

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Search page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="~/css/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="main">
        <!-- Another variation with a button -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Google & Bing" id="txtQuery">
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" id="btnSearch">
                    <i class="fa fa-search">Search</i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="searchResults">

        </div>

    </section>

    <script>
        $(function () {

            $("#btnSearch").click(function () {

                $("#searchResults").html("");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Bing", "Search")',
                    data: {
                        q: $("#txtQuery").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i in data) {
                            var item = data[i];
                            console.log(item.title);
                            var p = $("<p></p>").text(item.title);
                            $("#searchResults").append(p);

                           /* console.log(item.append);
                            var h = $(" < p ></p >").text(item.a);
                            $("#searchResults").url(h);*/

                        }
                        console.log("data received");
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Server error!");
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, just tried this and get the same - from the looks of things it's down to how bing works and basically doesn't want you harvesting search results

Comment: Do you mean that Parse Bing impossible?

Comment: well, rather than try and scrape which bing won't like there is a search api
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/cognitive-services/search-api/
https://mikedodaro.net/2018/02/22/bing-search-api/

I would say that scraping any website, isn't really friendly - depending on how often your hacking it. Your google code for example will at some point fail as good will recognise that your web server is hitting it a unusual amount of times and think "this isn't a person" and yeah block your server

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I understand it. But I don't need it for a long time. I can't use API in my project. It is requirements

Comment: why can't you use an API? That makes no sense. Unless your project is specifically to learn how to do web scraping? if so, then find a site which lets you scrape it. If not, then just use the API. HTML documents are intended for consumption by humans (after being rendered in a browser), not machines. APIs return machine-readable data (e.g. JSON or XML usually) which other automated programs can easily process. That's why they exist - so programs like yours can access the data in the site without having to try and parse complex HTML

Comment: Because it is my task - get data from chrome and bing without API. I undestand that it is much easier - use API, but...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well in the end I found the solution with a quick google. https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2019/06/16/parsing-html-data-with-c/

Still errors as the for loop search isn't correct but at least returns the results.

You'll have to modify to use in the API controller.

**Please do not use in production or anywhere live - in the end your site/server will get blocked by bing or google and thus render the code unusable. Please look at the API code instead. Also if google or microsoft modify there code/css etc then this will also break**

```
public class SearchController : Controller
    {

        public class SearchInfo
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Link { get; set; }

            public string BTitle { get; set; }
            public string BLink { get; set; }
        }

        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> DoBingSearchAsync(string q)
        {

            var html = @"https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + q;

            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134";

            var htmlDoc = await web.LoadFromWebAsync(html);




            var rows = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class='b_algo']").Take(5);

            var result = new List<SearchInfo>();
            foreach (HtmlNode row in rows)
            {
                var nodeRef = row.SelectSingleNode("./a");                //here could be  var nodeRef = row.SelectSingleNode("//a");      

                var si = new SearchInfo
                {

                    BLink = nodeRef.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty),
                    BTitle = nodeRef.InnerText.Trim()
                };

                result.Add(si);
            }

            return View(result);
        }
    }
```